# Trying to override a non-core admin controller

Tags: admin, controllers

So I have this module named `Thatcompany_Module`, and it has some admin controllers.
I'm trying to override one of these controllers with my custom module, named `Mycompany_MyModule`

This is what the original `routers` section looks like in `Thatcompany_Module` :

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <modulefrontname>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Thatcompany_Module</module>
                    <frontName>modulefrontname</frontName>
                </args>
            </modulefrontname>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <ThatCompany_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">ThatCompany_Module_Adminhtml</ThatCompany_Module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

What I've done yet, following advices found here and there on the Internet :

**My config :**

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mycompany_MyModule before="Thatcompany_Module">Mycompany_MyModule_Adminhtml</Mycompany_MyModule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

**And my controller :**

```
<?php
include_once('Thatcompany/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/TheControllerName.php');

class Mycompany_MyModule_Adminhtml_TheControllerName extends Thatcompany_Module_Adminhtml_TheControllerName
{
    // [...]
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working (I placed a big dirty die() in both index() actions, and the "Thatcompany" one displays instead of mine)

Any help, hint, link will be highly appreciated !

Comment: Can you post how the `routers` config section looks for the original module?

Comment: Hi Marius, I edited my post to add the original `routers` section

Comment: Hmmm...the code looks ok to me.

Comment: Also seems ok to me. But obviously, I missed something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally made it working (one of my coworkers, actually. Many thanks to him !).
Problem was on the xml config. Here is the good one :

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <modulefrontname>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mycompany_MyModule before="Thatcompany_Module">Mycompany_MyModule</Mycompany_MyModule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </modulefrontname>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

As you can see, I had to :

- Change from `<adminhtml>` route to `<modulefrontname>` (because THIS is the route I needed to override)
- Remove the `_Adminhtml` in the node value (and I have no idea why... If someone can explain...)

Comment: The first two things are used to find your module in `app/code/<community|local>/Mycompany/Mymodule` everything there after is suffixed after adding `controllers` to the path, so if you controller lives in `MyModule/controllers/Adminhtml`, add it, if not, don't add it :-)

Comment: This is the point : my controller **does** live in `MyModule/controllers/Adminhtml`. This is why I'm confused about this solution !

Comment: is your path `domain.com/module/adminhtml_controller/action` ?

Comment: Yes it is ! Is this the reason ?

Comment: Correct. If you add Adminhtml to the config, you can remove it from the url. It must somehow be added to the controller path or the controller is not found ;)

Comment: Thank you for this additional info. I wish I could +1 your comment like in stackoverflow.com ;)

Comment: You can, when you have more rep :-)